# How to combine words from lists into one?

Tags: python

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
```

How to combine these two lists into one, and the output should be
['ad', 'be', 'cf']

Comment: see how to use `zip` in python.

Comment: if I use zip, then the output is like: [('a','d'), ('b','e'), ('c','f')]

Answer (score 3):

You should use *zip* in conjunction with a list comprehension as follows:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']

list3 = [a+b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]

print(list3)
```

**Output:**

```
['ad', 'be', 'cf']
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will work:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']

list3 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
  list3.append(list1[i] + list2[i])

print(list3)
```

Output:

```
['ad', 'be', 'cf']
```

Explanation:

We will first create a new list, `list3` that will store the combination of `list1` and `list2`. To combine the two lists, we will use a for loop to iterate through every index of both `list1` and `list2` and then use the `.append()` function to add the `i`'th element of `list1` and `list2` to `list3`.

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you have any further questions or clarifications :)

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
for i in range(len(list1)):
     list1[i]+=list2[i]
print(list1)
#['ad', 'be', 'cf']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over several iterables in parallel, producing tuples with an item from each one and then concatinate them using `''.join(sequence)`.

```
In [2]: ["".join(i) for i in zip(list1, list2)]
Out[2]: ['ad', 'be', 'cf']
```